# Xtext indentation with single line comment

Tags: comments, indentation, xtext

I was having **problems with indentation and single line comments** in my xtext grammar. I tried the same thing in xtext example project

> *org.eclipse.xtext.example.homeautomation*

(*with Xtext installed, you can import this project like this:
File → New → Example → Xtext Examples → Xtext Home Automation Example*)
and results were the same. Is this and xtext bug? If so how can i open document and preparse it (to get rid of sl comments) and then give it to xtext lexer?

```
Device Window can be open, closed
Device Heater can be on, off, error

Rule 'Save energy' when Window.open then //asdasdd
    fire(Heater.off)
    println('Another penny to the piggy bank!')
```

[image]

**Marker text:**

> 1: - missing RULE_BEGIN at 'fire'
>
> 2: - mismatched input ''expecting RULE_END

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you file a ticket at eclipse for that

you may use the following workaround (dont know if there are negative side effects

```
terminal SL_COMMENT: '//' !('\n'|'\r')*;
```

Comment: thank you, it works without problems as far as i tested. Still there is problem with SL_COMMENTs, and this are SL_COMMENTs on empty lines, which cause error if not indented. I will file a ticket for that.